# library for persistent login with bearer token (with express as CLIENT)

Tags: node.js, express, authentication

I have to interface my express with an API of an external service. Express authenticates with bearer token, and every two hours it has to repeat the login and get a new token.

Is there already a good library that supports this scheme? (It's nothing complicated, I can easily write a sketch solution myself, but if there was something ready and tested I would like to use it)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken), this is a module that allows you to generate jwt tokens pretty easily but with many available options.